# Identify all accounts that do not yet have an account name in the Income Accounts table

Tags: sql

I have the below table that I need help with writing a query that identifies all of the accounts that do not yet have an account name:

[image: Click here to view picture]

The purpose of this table is to identify the name associated with the Income Accounts ID that can be found in the Fact table.

Below is a picture of a correlating table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wO1I.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @TierraWhite What is expected output here ?

Comment: `where name is null` ?

Comment: Hi @HarshGundecha , I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but, the purpose of this table is to identify the name associated with the Income Accounts ID that can be found in the Fact table. I will share a screenshot of the Fact table.

Answer (score 0):

When you say does not have a name would this be represented in your DB as null? If so, something like:

```
Select ID, NAME, TYPE from YOURTABLE where NAME is null
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @Tom - so, Select ID, NAME, TYPE from INCOME ACCOUNTS where NAME is null ?

Comment: From your description, yes I think so, although I assume INCOME ACCOUNTS is not your actual table name? If you have the record in the table but the name is not populated I would imagine this is represented as NULL in your table, and therfore you want to retrieve all account records where the name is null. Do I understand correctly? EDIT: I would also urge you to consider the reason why your DB/Application allows the account to be entered without a name in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Tom answers's, if you have 'empty' NAME records

1. Returning all records with null or empty NAME values

   ```
   Select ID, NAME, TYPE from YOURTABLE where ltrim(rtrim(isnull(NAME,''))) <> ''
   ```
2. Returning only the records with null or empty NAME values

   ```
   Select ID, NAME, TYPE from YOURTABLE where ltrim(rtrim(isnull(NAME,''))) = ''
   ```
3. Returning all records and identifies the null or empty NAME values with custom value

   ```
   Select ID, CASE WHEN (ltrim(rtrim(isnull(NAME,''))) = '') THEN 'Name not identified' else NAME end as NAME, TYPE from YOURTABLE
   ```